# A problem on continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

> $f : S^1 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous map. Define $$A = \{(x, y) \in S^1 \times S^1: x \neq y, f(x) = f(y)\}.$$
>   We want to prove that $A$ has uncountably many points.

It seems very evident, but I want a rigorous argument.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is a constant map, then there is nothing to prove. Otherwise, there exist $p,q\in S^1$, such that $f(p)<f(q)$. Denote the two open arcs joining $p$ and $q$ by $I$ and $J$. Since $I$ and $J$ are connected and $f$ is continuous, $f(I),f(J)\supset(f(p),f(q))$. It follows that for every $t\in(f(p),f(q))$, there exist $x\in I$ and $y\in J$, such that $f(x)=f(y)=t$, which completes the proof.

Comment: How does this complete the proof?

Comment: @julien: It has been shown that for the map $g:A\to \mathbb{R},(x,y)\mapsto f(x)$, $g(A)\supset(f(p),f(q))$, so $A$ must be uncountable.

Comment: Ah! That's a pretty slick argument...+1.